# SonarQube sonar.web.context causing issue filters to fail

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have SonarQube 5.1.1 installed and have several plugins as well.

I'm testing out the `sonar.web.context` parameter and it seems to be working just fine for the most part, but when I try to load or apply my saved Issues Filters, nothing loads and it gives me a 404 error in the console since the web context is missing. Is anyone else having these problems, or know a workaround for this issue? Removing the context param would get things back to normal, but having that web context would be nice to have.

Also, I'm seeing the same issue with the Views plugin. From the View's Settings page, after selecting a view and clicking "Open Dashboard", the page does not properly load and is missing the sonar.web.context. Typing in the missing web context string will allow it to load.

Answer (score 0):

I do confirm the issue. The [ticket](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6786) has been created (planned for SonarQube 5.2).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Looking forward to the upcoming release at the end of Q3.